# FFMPEG: Add outro to the end of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm a youtuber...and have more than 100 videos

My question is : how to add 1 outro clip to the end of all 100 videos ?

My question is : how to add 2 or more outro clips to the end of all 100 videos randomly ?

Thanks you guys !

Comment: Are your videos already uploaded to youtube? If so I don't think you use ffmpeg. You need to use YouTube Editor. If you haven't uploaded the 100 videos yet, you need to script ffmpeg

Comment: No....I don't upload it yet....I want to edit it and add outro to all 100 video before upload.....!

Comment: Can anyone help me plz ?

Comment: It also helps to tell us what OS and multimedia format container you are using, but I'll give you an answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

You want to concatenate the videos. see
https://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f

I don't know what OS or multimedia containers you have, so read that FAQ. Especially if you want to avoid making potentially huge intermediate files.

In Linux/Mac OSX you want something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate1.mpg
ffmpeg -i input2.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate2.mpg
cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg
ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -qscale:v 2 output.avi
```

On  Windows I think the syntax is:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate1.mpg
ffmpeg -i input2.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate2.mpg
copy intermediate1.mpg+intermediate2.mpg intermediate_all.mpg
ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -qscale:v 2 output.avi
```

If your multimedia containers are already MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, or DV you can skip the transcoding steps and just concat using `cat` or `copy` or better yet `concat` protocol.

You can get fancy with scripting to add pseudo-randomisation to add the Outro. But I'd just add outroA to all odd numbered files and outroB to all even numbered files.

If you want to add more that one outro to your content randomly, I'm not that good a command line hacker to pipe and nest randomisations. So I'd build the randomisation (aka spinning) of 100 `cat/copy/concat` lines into a script via a spreadsheet, then copy/paste the script into a batch/shell script.